# Java Selenium - navigating with the website's page-navigator gets stuck

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to move through website pages using the website's page navigator, but it always stops clicking at page 13.

This is the page navigator:
[image]

This is my code:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numOfPages; i++) {
    customWebDriver.getWebDriver().findElement(By.className("css-3a6490")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

This is the HTML structure:
[image]

I have also tried using the element under css-3a6490, **css-15a7b5o**:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numOfPages; i++) {
    customWebDriver.getWebDriver().findElement(By.className("css-15a7b5o")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);
}
```

but it also didn't work.

Does someone knows what is the problem?
Thanks

Comment: https://golden.com/query/list-of-software-as-a-service-companies-BMY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
customWebDriver.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='css-19a323y']//following-sibling::button[1]")).click();
```

**Explanation of Xpath:** A button with class css-19a323y (Which is the current selected page) and then selecting the following button (Which is the next available page)

Also use more time for `Thread.sleep(3000);` because sometimes when you make pagination it takes more time, so better add more time, or using WebdriverWait and Expected conditions, here an example:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id<locator>));
```